# Android socket not created

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing an Android app that is going to send camera stream to a Node.js web server by Socket. When the app has to create the socket the app doesn't execute the code inside the try statement but even though launchs any catch exception.

MyThread.java

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    OutputStream os = null;

    try {Log.d("MyCameraApp", "HERE1");
        mSocket = new Socket(ip, port);

        if (mSocket != null) {Log.d("MyCameraApp", "SOCKET CONNECTED");

            try {
                os = mSocket.getOutputStream();

                while (true) {
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    dos.writeInt(4);
                    dos.writeUTF("#@@#");
                    dos.writeInt(mFrameBuffer.size());
                    dos.writeUTF("-@@-");
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.write(mFrameBuffer.toByteArray());
                    dos.flush();
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / 15);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    if (os != null)
                        os.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "SOCKET NULL");
        }

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "CATCH SOCKET");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

CameraActivity.java

```
try {
    mThread = new MyThread(getApplicationContext(), SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
    mThread.execute();Log.d("MyCameraApp", "WELL DONE");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "CATCH");
}
```

The CameraActivity create a mThread object and the app only displays the log 'HERE1' inside the try, before the socket is created and then displays the log 'WELL DONE'.

I have a basic Node.js server that only is listening in the correspondent port, nothing else.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you give the corresponding permission to your app? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Yes, the app has the permission to access Internet

Comment: can you please share the values for the variables ip and port? Are you sure that they are provided?

Comment: What does 'even though launchs any catch exception' mean?

Comment: The values are ip="192.168.235.11" and port=8080. I'm testing the app in a devide that is connected the same network where also is connected the pc where is the local server that has that ip address.

Comment: It means that the app don't execute the try statement because enters in but don't continues and don't execute any catch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android device was connected by wifi and the pc was connected by Ethernet... differents subnets.